# Proving $(n+1)^n > 2^n n!$

Tags: inequality

If $n>1$ is a natural number, how to prove that

$$(n+1)^n > 2^n n!$$

Comment: What have you tried? Your questions always read: "how to prove (fill in something homeworkish)." Please show a little bit of your own efforts and read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/5363

Comment: Are you allowed to use Stirling?

Comment: @J.M. This follows from AM GM

Comment: Stirling here seems like a pretty big hammer to squash a little  bug.

Comment: @Peter, I thought of that a few seconds after writing that comment. I'm getting lazy...

Comment: @J.M. However, I don't oppose to using any tool available.

Comment: I like your question. (+1)

Comment: See [How can I show that $n! \leqslant (\frac{n+1}{2})^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/992056) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/992056).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the AM GM inequality, $$\eqalign{
  & \root n \of {n!}  = \root n \of {1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots n}  \leq \frac{{1 + 2 + 3 +  \cdots  + n}}{n}  \cr 
  & \frac{{\left( {n + 1} \right)n}}{{2n}} = \frac{{n + 1}}{2} \cr} $$

Then $$n! \leq {\left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)^n}$$ as desired.

Answer (score 6):

Prove it by induction on $n$. The base case $n=2$ is trivial. For the induction step you want to show that if $(n+1)^n>2^nn!$, then $(n+2)^{n+1}>2^{n+1}(n+1)!$. This will certainly be true if

$$\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^n}\ge \frac{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}{2^nn!}=2(n+1)\;.\tag{1}$$

The inequality $(1)$ is equivalent to the inequality

$$\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\ge 2\;.$$

Now use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the following auxiliary sequence:
 $$u_{n}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{2^n n!}$$
Then we notice the sequence is strictly increasing
$$ \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1} (n+1)!} \cdot \frac{2^n n!}{(n+1)^n}= \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} > 1\space \ \tag1 $$
and
$$u_{2}= \frac{9}{8} \tag2$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get the needed inequality
$$(n+1)^n > 2^n n!$$

Q.E.D.