# How can I show that $n! \leqslant \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction, factorial

> Show that $$n! \leqslant \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n \quad \hbox{for all } n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I know that it can be done by induction but I always find line where I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the AM-GM inequality on the numbers $1,...,n$.

Comment: Very nice hint. +1

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$
(n!)^2 = 1\times n \times 2\times (n-1) \times \dots
= \prod_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k)
$$
then use
$$
k\times (n+1 -k) =
\left(\frac {n+1}2 + \frac {n+1}2 - k\right)\left(\frac {n+1}2 - \frac {n+1}2 + k\right)
\\= \left(\frac {n+1}2\right)^2 - \left( \frac {n+1}2 - k\right)^2
\le \left(\frac {n+1}2\right)^2
$$
to get
$$
(n!)^2 \le \left(\frac {n+1}2\right)^{2n}
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$(n!)^2 = \prod_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k) \leq  \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{k+n+1-k}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)^{2n}$$

Comment: Words can be useful.

Comment: @Alizter not always

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac{r+n+1-r}2\ge\sqrt{r(n-r)}$$  for $1\le r\le n$

Set $r=1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$ and then multiply