# Proof of $ n! \lt \Big(\frac{n+1}{2}\Big)^n$

Tags: inequality

> Use $AM $-$GM$ inequality to show that $$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})  : n! \lt \Bigg(\frac{n+1}{2}\Bigg)^n$$ .

Comment: $$\dfrac{r+(n+1-r)}2\ge?$$ for $r>0,n+1-r>0$

Comment: kindly include your attempt if possible.

Comment: Your question would be much better if you [provided context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). I strongly encourage you to read the Q/A I linked to and edit your question accordingly. For example, you don't even tell us where does your question come from, or if you know what AM-GM inequality is, how you've tried to apply it...

Comment: I've already voted to close as "missing context", but it's also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992056/how-can-i-show-that-n-leqslant-fracn12n)

Answer (score 5):

We have $$\sqrt[n]{n!}=\sqrt[n]{1\cdot 2\cdot …\cdot n}\le \frac{1+2+...+n}{n}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I would appreciate if you continue

Comment: @custumuzer There is nothing to continue: you only need to read carefully the above answer and write half a line more and then you have what you want!

Comment: @custumuzer. Try to carefully compare the answer that has been provided to the original question and you will see what needs to be done

Comment: Beautiful solution! +1.

Answer (score 1):

Inequality problems are all about finding small patterns. Often you can start from some modest equations. Let $a,b$ are positive numbers.

Such that $a+b=m$

Then, $ab=a(m-a)=am-a^2=\frac{m^2}{4}-(a-m/2)^2$

This means $ab$ is maximum when $a=b=m/2$.

Take, $a+b=n+1$

Hence
$$1\cdot2\cdots n=(1\cdot n)(2\cdot (n-1))\cdots \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\leq \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n$$

You can easily work out cases when $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: I've fixed your equtions with MathJax, but the math is just wrong.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudD. But where is the Math wrong?

Comment: Second equation, $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=\frac{-a^2+2ab-b^2}{4}=-\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2$ and not $ab$. (The square on the first term gives you a $4$ in the denominator instead of a $2$)

Comment: Your last equation was also problematic, but I think I see what you're doing now. Except the second factor in the middle should be $2\cdot (n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt[n]{x_0\cdot x_1\cdot x_2\cdot...\cdot x_n} \leq \frac {x_0+x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$$

$$n! = n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-3)\cdot...\cdot 1$$

Using the AM-GM inequality, we can conclude:

$$\sqrt[n] {n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-3)\cdot...\cdot 1} \leq \frac{1+...+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n}{n}$$

Simplify the right hand side.

$$\sqrt[n] {n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-3)\cdot...\cdot 1} \leq n\biggr(\frac{n+1}{2n}\biggr)$$

Simplify again and raise both sides to power $n$.

$$n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-3)\cdot...\cdot 1 \leq \biggr(\frac{n+1}{2}\biggr)^n$$

$$n! \leq \biggr(\frac{n+1}{2}\biggr)^n$$

Proven.